# PHP Where Should I define my class constants and variables, should I create a base class or an abstract class or just use a the same class

Tags: php, class, yii, abstract-class

I have a class where I have defined lot of constants and instance variables which are strings and arrays.
I wanted to separate these constants and variable from my current class, which after separation will contain only methods. 
I want to know If I should keep these constants in a separate class which I will extend like a base class or an abstract class with an abstract method or just use the same current class.

I have 29 private instance variables and approx 50 constant variables;
example some of my constans and variables

```
const HOME      = 'Home';
const KEYZERO   = '0';
const BC_FLAG   = 'bcrFlag';

private $arrayAllparameters = array('form_id','startDate','endDate');
private $arrEncryptedParameters     = array('form_id','layoutId');
private $arrayUrlEncodeParameter    = array('apiType', 'form_id');
```

Comment: No, classes are about modularity for functionality.  Not a way to organize data.  Separating them for data reasons alone would only Obfuscate the class IMO.  Also `private` properties are not accessible by a child class. For [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3eac23abbafeef89d7445972fb28f96fcef7802)

Comment: Further if you have that many properties and constants, you may want to look at [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) concepts.  It deals mainly with defining a single purpose or responsibility to a single class.  Likely you are doing to much in 1 place.  You can write procedural code in a class, something to be avoided.  Besides all that, this is way to broad for SO.

Comment: Like ArtisticPhoenix mentioned, read a bit more about SOLID. It seems like you have way to much responsibility for a single class.